# R : adding a new column to an existing dataframe with a condition

Tags: r, dataframe

Note: Non of the already existing answers solved my problem

df1:

```
   asn  used    domain_used
    1   9928    2594
    2   2048    100
    3   1792    170
    4   57344   991
    5   36864   1173
    6   24576   194
    7   26624   226
    8   15360   584
    9   65792   3003
    10  1427968 32904
    11  13312   266
    12  28672   388
```

I would like to sort this dataframe based on domain_used column and create a new column called "top_bad" to be =1 if an "asn"  is in top 10 rows(when sorted). Can any body help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this :

```
df1<-df1[order(df1$domain_used),] # sort the data.frame according to domain_used
df1$top_bad <- 0                  # create new variable top_bad and set values to 0 for each row
df1$top_bad[1:10] <- 1            # set top_bad to 1 for the first 10 values
```

answer your question ?

Comment: This worked thank you @CathG. The only question that I dont understand is that why you use (-1) here? What does the - imply in R notation?

Comment: @user2058811, I don't, I use `<-` to assign values to df1$top_bad

Comment: @user2058811, I edited my answer to add explanations

Answer (score 5):

Or if you want to modify your data set by reference, try the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setorder(setDT(df1), domain_used)[1:10, top_bad := 1]
```

Or if you want zeroes instead on `NA`s

```
setorder(setDT(df1), domain_used)[, top_bad := c(1:10, rep(0, .N - 10))]
```